# how to print view title in views-view-unformatted.html.twig?

Tags: views, theming

[image]I have to style the view title 
and print it in the unformatted twig. how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 8):

As per @Clive's comment

```
{{ view.getTitle() }}
```

Comment: Why the extra bit getting the route title? It seems `$view->getTitle()` is all you need, see for example [`views_ui_preprocess_views_view `](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views_ui%21views_ui.module/function/views_ui_preprocess_views_view/8.2.x). In the twig template that would translate to a simple `{{ view.getTitle() }}` (you know the View is already in `$vars` right? No need to load it again)

Comment: I would swear I had tried it !! but I guess my installation was messed up ... on a new installation it works !!! Thanks

Comment: I applied your answer and the result was great..!! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

How do I get the URL value in the views-view-unformatted--domains_devs.html.twig?  I'm using D10.

`<a href="[My_Link]"/>Go to Link</a>`